# With Rails System Test my custom Devise is allowing login without authentication. How is this possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm struggling with a bug that I hope someone can help me with.  If this is the wrong place to ask, let me know.

So I've written my own custom authenticator with Devise... essentially one the 1st loging attemp, the user must enter the username, password and mfa. On subsequent logins, the user only needs to enter their username and mfa.

This duo authentication scheme seems to work fine when I am manually excercising it.   At least I haven't seen it fail in the 4 weeks since I've been running it.

When I run it via rails (6.1.4.6) system test feature this is what happens:

1. Login with username, password plus mfa.
2. Logout.
3. The username is entered into an input field and the "Next" button is clicked.
4. At this point, the mfa input box should be presented.  Instead Devise redirects to an internal page that should only be accessible after the user authenticates!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is difficult to answer without some code and implementation details of your authenticator; a test log maybe.

Comment: "How is this possible?" - You tell us. We have no idea if your devise implementation actually is correctly setup or if the controller under test is actually autenticating the user. Without any sort of reproducable example this really just boils down to classic unanswerable "Has anybody had a similar issue?" question.